# CustomList not added into fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, custom-lists

I have been stuck here for quite some time. I'm using async task to retrieve a list of events and adding them into a list view within a fragment. However, it does not show up. Can some one tell me what is wrong? It'll be a great help.

Here's the fragment's codes:

```
public static class EventsSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    SharedPreferences settings = null;
    Editor editor;
    ListView list;
    TextView noEventsTv;

    public EventsSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        recLifeCycle_with_savedInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);

        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        noEventsTv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.norecordsTV);

        new GetEventsAsyncTask((MainActivity) getActivity()).execute();

        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        return rootView;
    }

    public void updateEventList(final List<Event> eventList)
    {

        Log.i("updateEventList:eventlist.count", String.valueOf(eventList.size()));

        if (eventList.size() > 0) 
        {

            Log.i("CustomList", "Start customlist inflation");
            CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), eventList);

            noEventsTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    String eventSel = eventList.get(position).getEvent_id();
                    event_id = eventSel;
                    // direct to event details fragment
                    startEventDetailsFragment();
                }
            });
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.invalidateViews();
        } 
        else 
        {
            noEventsTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Here's the async task that retrieves the events:

```
public class GetEventsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>{

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
MainActivity activityMain;
Boolean ticketValid=false;
List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();

public GetEventsAsyncTask(MainActivity parent)
{
    activityMain = parent;
}

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressDialog = null;

         if (progressDialog == null) 
         {
               progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activityMain);
               progressDialog.setMessage("download events, please wait...");
               progressDialog.show();
               progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
               progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
         }   
    }

      @Override
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean error = false;
            try {
                error = postData();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return error;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Boolean error){          
             /* if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                  progressDialog.dismiss();
                  progressDialog = null;
              } */
              if(error==true)
              {
                  Log.i("GetEvents", "Error at get events");
                  activityMain.errorOccured();
              }
              else
              {
                  Log.i("onPostExecute:eventlist.count",String.valueOf(eventList.size()));
                  MainActivity.myDB.removeAllEvents();
                  for(int i=0;i<eventList.size();i++)
                  {
                      MainActivity.myDB.insertEventEntry(eventList.get(i));
                  }
                  activityMain.downloadEventsSuccess(eventList);

              }

      } 

      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
      }


    public Boolean postData() throws JSONException {

        Boolean error = false;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      // specify the URL you want to post to

        try {

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Constants.HOST_NAME+"/"+Constants.SERVICE_NAME+"/api/event?userId=S6871919D");
            BufferedReader reader;
            StringBuffer sb;
            String line = "";
            String NL="";
            String json;
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
            {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                 sb = new StringBuffer("");
                 line = "";
                 NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }

                reader.close();
                json = sb.toString();

                Log.i("event json",json);
                try
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);   

                    for (int i = 0, length = jsonArray.length(); i < length; i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Event eventObj =  new Event(); 
                        eventObj.setEvent_id(attribute.getString("event_id"));
                        eventObj.setEvent_title(attribute.getString("event_title"));
                        eventObj.setEvent_desc(attribute.getString("event_desc"));
                        eventObj.setStart_date(attribute.getString("start_date"));
                        eventObj.setEnd_date(attribute.getString("end_date"));
                        eventObj.setStart_time(attribute.getString("start_time"));
                        eventObj.setEnd_time(attribute.getString("end_time"));
                        eventObj.setLocation(attribute.getString("location"));
                        eventObj.setPicture_path(attribute.getString("picture_path"));
                        eventObj.setSmall_picture_path(attribute.getString("small_picture_path"));

                        eventList.add(eventObj);
                        eventObj = null;
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                error = true;
            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // process execption
            error = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // process execption
            error = true;
        }
        return error;

    }
```

Here's the customList's codes:

```
private final Activity context;
private final List<Event> eventsList;

public CustomList(Activity context, List<Event> eventsList) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single);
    this.context = context;
    this.eventsList = eventsList;


}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    //set up the inflater...
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);

    //reference the widgets...
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    TextView txtDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    Log.i("CustomList", "Start customList");

    txtTitle.setText(eventsList.get(position).getEvent_title());
    txtDate.setText(eventsList.get(position).getStart_date());
    new GetEventsImageAsyncTask(imageView).execute(Constants.HOST_NAME + "/"+ Constants.CMS_NAME+ "/" +eventsList.get(position).getSmall_picture_path());

    Log.i("CustomList", "End customList");

    return rowView;
}
```

Here's the async task that retrieves the images from the server:

```
public class GetEventsImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView;

    public GetEventsImageAsyncTask(ImageView imageView){
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String urls = url[0];
        Bitmap icon = null;

        try
        {
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(urls).openStream();
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("GetEventImage", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return icon;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
```

Here's the xml for the custom list:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_single"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
        android:text="Placeholder" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
        android:text="Placeholder" />
```

This is the event fragment's xml:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/fragment_events"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/bg">

        <ListView
           android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
        </ListView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/norecordsTV"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/no_events"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The codes do not even go to CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), eventList); and I don't know why. The events are retrieved properly btw.

EDIT:

Here's the logcat:

```
10-10 12:56:44.193: I/updateEventList:eventlist.count(16963): 4
10-10 12:56:56.473: I/MYTAG(16963): FacilitiesSectionFragment.onPause
10-10 12:56:56.473: I/MYTAG(16963): FacilitiesSectionFragment.onStop
10-10 12:56:56.473: I/MYTAG(16963): FacilitiesSectionFragment.onDestroyView
10-10 12:56:56.553: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 25
10-10 12:56:56.553: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 26
10-10 12:56:56.553: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 27
10-10 12:56:56.553: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 28
10-10 12:56:56.553: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 29
10-10 12:56:56.553: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 30
10-10 12:56:56.553: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 31
10-10 12:56:56.553: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 32
10-10 12:56:56.563: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 33
10-10 12:56:56.563: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 34
10-10 12:56:56.563: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 35
10-10 12:56:56.563: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 36
10-10 12:56:56.563: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 37
10-10 12:56:56.563: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 38
10-10 12:56:56.563: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 39
10-10 12:56:56.563: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 40
10-10 12:56:56.563: I/dalvikvm(16963): Total arena pages for JIT: 41
10-10 12:56:57.333: I/MYTAG(16963): FacilitiesSectionFragment.onCreateView / savedInstanceState == null
10-10 12:56:57.333: I/MYTAG(16963): FacilitiesSectionFragment.onStart
10-10 12:56:57.333: I/MYTAG(16963): FacilitiesSectionFragment.onResume
10-10 12:56:57.383: I/facility json(16963): [{"facility_id":"ITM00000002","facility_name":"Libary","facility_desc":"The Nanyang Polytechnic Library provides a rich and diverse collection of resources to serve the information and research needs of staff and students.","requires_booking":"N","school_code":"ARO","open_hrs":"0900","close_hrs":"2100","open_for_book":null,"picture_path":"Data/Sites/1/uploads/alumniAdmin_Facility_2014-09-22_03-51-30.png","small_picture_path":"Data/Sites/1/uploads/alumniAdmin_Facility_2014-09-22_03-30-54.png","close_from":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","close_to":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","fee":"0.00"},{"facility_id":"ITM00000004","facility_name":"Table Tennis","facility_desc":"Table Tennis for playing  table tennis","requires_booking":"N","school_code":"ARO","open_hrs":"0900","close_hrs":"2100","open_for_book":null,"picture_path":"Data/Sites/1/uploads/alumniAdmin_Facility_2014-09-22_03-31-44.png","small_picture_path":"Data/Sites/1/uploads/alumniAdmin_Facility_2014-09-22_03-31-44.jpg","close_from":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","close_to":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","fee":"3.00"},{"facility_id":"ITM00000009","facility_name":"Badminton Court Pass","facility_desc":"Badminton Court Pass","requires_booking":"N","school_code":"ARO","open_hrs":"0900","close_hrs":"2100","open_for_book":null,"picture_path":"Data/Sites/1/uploads/leowzzaro_Facility_2014-10-08_11-29-05.png","small_picture_path":"Data/Sites/1/uploads/leowzzaro_Facility_2014-10-08_11-29-05.jpg","close_from":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","close_to":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","fee":"0.00"},{"facility_id":"ITM00000014","facility_name":"Badminton Court","facility_desc":"Badminton Court for playing badminton","requires_booking":"Y","school_code":"ARO","open_hrs":"0900","close_hrs":"2100","open_for_book":null,"picture_path":"Data/Sites/1/uploads/leowzzaro_Facility_2014-10-08_11-22-44.png","small_picture_path":"Data/Sites/1/uploads/leowzzaro_Facility_2014-10-08_11-22-44.jpg","close_from":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","close_to":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","fee":"3.00"}]
10-10 12:56:57.393: I/onPostExecute:facilityList.count(16963): 4
10-10 12:56:57.403: W/MY_LOG(16963): Removing Entries from facilities Success
10-10 12:56:57.403: W/MY_LOG(16963): Inserted EntryName=Libary into table facilities
10-10 12:56:57.433: W/MY_LOG(16963): Inserted EntryName=Table Tennis into table facilities
10-10 12:56:57.453: W/MY_LOG(16963): Inserted EntryName=Badminton Court Pass into table facilities
10-10 12:56:57.493: W/MY_LOG(16963): Inserted EntryName=Badminton Court into table facilities
10-10 12:56:57.513: I/updateEventList:eventlist.count(16963): 4
10-10 12:57:06.523: I/MYTAG(16963): EcardSectionFrontFragment.onPause
10-10 12:57:06.523: I/MYTAG(16963): EcardSectionFrontFragment.onStop
10-10 12:57:06.533: I/MYTAG(16963): EcardSectionFrontFragment.onDestroyView
10-10 12:57:06.533: I/MYTAG(16963): TicketSectionFragment.onCreateView / savedInstanceState == null
10-10 12:57:06.543: I/MYTAG(16963): TicketSectionFragment.onStart
10-10 12:57:06.543: I/MYTAG(16963): TicketSectionFragment.onResume
10-10 12:57:14.203: I/MYTAG(16963): EcardSectionFrontFragment.onCreateView / savedInstanceState == null
10-10 12:57:14.203: I/MYTAG(16963): TicketSectionFragment.onPause
10-10 12:57:14.203: I/MYTAG(16963): TicketSectionFragment.onStop
10-10 12:57:14.203: I/MYTAG(16963): TicketSectionFragment.onDestroyView
10-10 12:57:14.203: I/MYTAG(16963): EcardSectionFrontFragment.onStart
10-10 12:57:14.203: I/MYTAG(16963): EcardSectionFrontFragment.onResume
```

Comment: There's no error within the logcat. But I'll post it anyways.

Comment: Are u sure your eventList size is > 0? if u didnt check this part, do put a Log in that area and be sure it is greater than 0 values..

Comment: 10-10 13:55:11.923: I/List Size(17591): 6
I've checked. It's more than 0.

Comment: use a getcount method in your customlist adapter like this @Override
 public int getCount()
 {
  if (List.size() <= 0)
  {
   return 0;
  }
  return List.size();
 }

Comment: Adding the getCount worked! However, there was only 1 entry.

Comment: Any way your problem is solved.. entry is not the matter..

Comment: I will put this as a answer.. make a tick..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CustomList Adapter does not have a count of list, so by adding this below methods will resolve the problem..

```
@Override public int getCount()
{
 if (List.size() <= 0)
 {
  return 0;
  }
 return List.size();
 }

@Override
public Event getItem(int position)
{
    return List.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}
```

Comment: However, it still only shows one entry. What more should I add within the getView of customList so that it shows all entries?

Comment: There's an error when I change return of getItem to an Object.
The return type is incompatible with ArrayAdapter<String>.getItem(int). This error is on the return type when I try changing it from String to an Object

Comment: @AurorerD.Wysteria you have to change it to Event for return an item from getItem method.. since your list contains list of events.. Check my edit..

Comment: I did. However, it gave me the error I stated in my previous comment.